# How do I add a page using Page Title under 'Default Selection' which contains commas in Data Studio?

Tags: looker-studio

I have a Data Studio filter set up for different blog posts that are predefined by using 'Page Title' as the dimension and then under Default Section adding the page title for each blog.

I have one page title that uses commas in the title, however the list is separated using commas. I've tried using adding quotation marks (") with no joy. Are there any workarounds to this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the default selection of the [Filter Control](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6312144) - It can be achieved by adding the escape sequence `\` before the comma; for example, to capture the text:

```
A,B,C
```

`\` would be added before each comma thus:

```
A\,B\,C
```

[Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/b5db297e-42a0-4bbb-9651-89909a56269f) and a GIF to elaborate:

[image]